# Список слов строки без знаков препинания

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list

Допустим, есть строка:

> abracadabra! Abac. BaBca, cab

Мне надо получить список из слов без знаков препинания и пробелов.

Как это сделать? Желательно в одну строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import string

s = 'abracadabra! Abac. BaBca, cab'

print(s.translate(str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation))).split())
```

Answer (score 2):

через регулярки

```
import re

my_str='abracadabra! Abac. BaBca, cab'

print(re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', my_str))
```

`\w+` - любое количество букв
`\b` - Начало или конец слова (слева пусто или не-буква, справа буква и наоборот).

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w+', my_str)` тоже сработает, "плюс" будет максимум символов захватывать (т.е. слово целиком).

Comment: @insolor так оно же и так вроде бы выводить будет слово целиком , разве что использовать \b излишне и  ваша запись короче или есть еще отличия?

Comment: Да, я имел в виду что `\b` излишне